# Parsing Wordpress Json Output

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I want to parse this I tried almost everything but I couldn't understand this , I m getting this from WordPress database table wp_postmeta.
Tried - unserialize , serialize, json_encode

```
string(303) "s:294:"a:1:{i:2364;a:1:{s:9:"schedules";a:1:{s:13:"578db85b83681";a:5:{s:13:"minutes_start";s:3:"540";s:11:"minutes_end";s:4:"1020";s:5:"weeks";a:6:{i:0;s:2:"on";i:1;s:2:"on";i:2;s:2:"on";i:3;s:2:"on";i:4;s:2:"on";i:6;s:2:"on";}s:10:"date_start";s:10:"07/18/2016";s:8:"date_end";s:10:"09/30/2016";}}}}";"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. What errors are you getting?

Comment: there in no error when i doing var_dump  getting this

Comment: That is a string generated by `serialize()` so it should `unserialize()` unless there is an error in the string

Comment: Yup: The `"s:294:` does not belong in that encoding

Comment: you are right here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [unserialize()](http://www.unserialize.com/s/11b9b70e-37ef-b0c9-0a18-00005eb44f2e). This worked.